# Bootstrap Pills Tabs: Next and Previous buttons not work perfectly

Tags: javascript, html

**Using Django Framework, Bootstrap v4.5.2.**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-dark nav-fill bg-dark" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link text-light active" id="pills-one-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-one" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-one" aria-selected="true">One</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link text-light" id="pills-two-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-two" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-two" aria-selected="false">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link text-light" id="pills-three-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-three" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-three" aria-selected="false">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content pb-3" id="pills-tabContent">

  <div class="tab-pane fade show active p-3 text-center" id="pills-one" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-one-tab">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next &#8594;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade p-3 text-center" id="pills-two" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-two-tab"> 
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> &#8592; Previous</a>
    <a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext ">Next &#8594;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade p-3 text-center" id="pills-three" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-three-tab"> 
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> &#8592; Previous</a>
  </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btnNext').click(function() {
        $('.nav-pills .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });
    
    $('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
        $('.nav-pills .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

I tried all the javascript seeing stackoverflow others answer but this does not work for me

**How can I solve this to work perfectly?**
If anything is a mistake on my code or you want to give me some suggestions, then reply to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

You can add   `e.preventDefault();` in **click()** event.

**base.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-DrT5NfxfbHvMHux31Lkhxg42LY6of8TaYyK50jnxRnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then add in Bootstrap Pills Tab's html instead of adding CDN.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

```js
$('.btnNext').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.nav-pills .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.nav-pills .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-DrT5NfxfbHvMHux31Lkhxg42LY6of8TaYyK50jnxRnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-dark nav-fill bg-dark" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link text-light active" id="pills-one-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-one" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-one" aria-selected="true">One</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link text-light" id="pills-two-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-two" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-two" aria-selected="false">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link text-light" id="pills-three-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-three" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-three" aria-selected="false">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content pb-3" id="pills-tabContent">

  <div class="tab-pane fade show active p-3 text-center" id="pills-one" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-one-tab">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next &#8594;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade p-3 text-center" id="pills-two" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-two-tab"> 
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> &#8592; Previous</a>
    <a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext ">Next &#8594;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade p-3 text-center" id="pills-three" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-three-tab"> 
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> &#8592; Previous</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting this error in the console. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. HOW TO FIX?

Comment: Beacuse you not added [Jquery cdn](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js).

Comment: Please add exact css and js properly. [More info visit](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: YES, IT WORKED! on jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js. But Why it's not working on jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I know you are a New Contributor in SO. if you are happy from this answer, don't forgot [to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I updated answer with  jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js cdn working :)

Comment: When I add cdn to base HTML file it's doesn't work but adding on the same HTML file it work.What happen?

Comment: can you extend the base HTML in the file. that is `{% extends "base.html" %}`

Comment: Yes, I did when I create a new file.

Comment: I think (jquery.min.js) cause that. I have use this in same file for uploading image.